# TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Union

Tags: ruby, arel

I am performing a union over two subsets of my *domain* table with `cnt` being a local variable, using arel 2.0.9 and [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) 0.8.5 as query interface.

```
def bla cnt
    Domain.group { some_id }.select { `*` }.select { count(`*`).as(`cnt`) }.having { `cnt` >= cnt }
end
```

Now when building the union of two calls say `cnt(1).union(cnt(1))` I get a `Arel::Nodes::Union` instance.

How do I use this relation to actually get my results? Calling `#each` yields the very same `Arel::Nodes::Union` reference and `#to_sql` results in an `TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Union`.

Any ideas? I *could* write the query differently, e.g. by using conditional logic (doable in arel?) ...

Comment: This seems to be the same issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/939. It's unclear why it was closed though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I am understanding you right, but to get a union of two or more separate queries, you can use the followng approach:

```
scope :union, lambda { |a, b| where{id.in(Model.where{attr1.eq a}) | id.in(Model.where{attr2.eq b}) } }
```

It's a little ugly, but I am not aware of any other approach...

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object into a `Arel::Nodes::SelectStatement`, you can easily do this by way of `Relation#ast`:

```
union = Arel::Nodes::Union.new( cnt(1).ast, cnt(1).ast )
Domain.find_by_sql( union.to_sql )
```

Comment: There's no `to_sql` instance method on `Arel::Nodes::Union` (as of Rails 3.2.1).

Comment: @Dmytrii no, but it does exist on the superclass `Arel::Nodes::Node`. I've verified that this still works in 3.2.2

Comment: I'm getting "method not found" when trying to call it. Are you sure that works for you?

Comment: @Dmytrii Yes, I created a Rails 3.2 test app